# Controlling Android system keyboard with gamepad

Tags: android, keyboard, gamepad

I created android game what is well controllable with touchscreen. After some time users requested possibility control user interface only with gamepad. I added something like "top most" cursor controlled with left analog stick. Based on cursor coordinates I send `MotionEvent` to view below cursor. Everything works great. But sometimes I need enter text to `TextBoxes`. Sending `MotionEvent` to `TextBox` calls and displays system keyboard, but here it ends, because I don't know how to send `MotionEvent` to system keyboard.

The only solution what I got on mind is override `TextBox's` request keyboard event and showing my own custom keyboard which I can control.

Is there any other solution?

Thank you